# Crossproduct/join with data.table using a function

Tags: r, data.table

I wonder, if it is possible to do an efficient cross join with data table for some specific taks.

Let's say I have a vectorized version of comparing all numbers in a vector agains all other numbers. If I am not mistaken, then a vectorized version of it in R would be

```
somevector <- rnorm(10, 5)
sapply(somevector, function(x) {
  return(x-somevector)
})
```

Is it possible to produce the same matrix with data.table? Will it be efficient?

Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can use `outer(somevector,somevector,'-')`, which is faster than your approach.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I run your snippet but I coul not get faster results

`somevector <- rnorm(10000, 5)
    system.time(sapply(somevector, function(x) {return(x-somevector)}))
    system.time(outer(somevector, somevector, '-'))`

Comment: On my system `outer` is faster by a factor of two. You might have run out of RAM, making writing to disk the bottle neck for speed. `data.table` does some impressive magic, but I am not sure it can speed up this operation. Though it might help with the memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

`expand.grid` does what would be called a cross join in SQL. You can use it to easily subtract the two vectors.

```
x<-1:7
somevector <- rnorm(10, 5)
df<-(expand.grid(x,somevector))
df[,1]-df[,2]
```

Comment: I did not know about expand grid, thank you. Although it produces vectors the runtime is still worse than with `sapply` and `outer`. And I think memory is an issue here. I tried to `expand.grid` with a 20k dim vector and I run out of memory quite fast.